# Selected element cannot be deselected when select attribute is set

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

Hi have a dropdown list that is filled with data from database.

```
<select name="form[entities][]" multiple="true">
        {% for entity in entities %}
            {% if entity.selected %}

            <option value="{{ entity.id }}" selected="selected">
                 {{ entity.name }}
            </option>

            {% else %}

            <option value="{{ entity.id }}">{{ entity.name }}</option>

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

If an entity was previously slected it will be rendered as selected.

I can switch selections, that means I can select another entity and the previous one will be deselected. But e.g. if there is only one item and it is selected it cannot be deselected it simply stays selected.

So my question is, is this normal behaviour? The field is not required. Is there a way to handle deselection just using html or do I have to introduce another button and handle deselection with javascript?

Comment: How about adding another option - a blank option?

Comment: Sounds good actually, however I remember this should work without blank option, but I am not sure.

Comment: @artworkad you can't deselect that only one option. I think you should go with Joe's solution. Maybe, you can use this to add blank option if  select has only one children: http://jsfiddle.net/XFv4M/ It is default behaviour of select.

Comment: Thx! Please, one of you, post this as an answer.

Comment: oh sorry new fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XFv4M/1/ say this to Joe because he first said this. I was late to see this question.

Comment: just use **CTRL** to deselect last selected option

Comment: @vlcekmi3 Aww that works but does a normal user know that?

Comment: imo it is normal behaviour

Comment: I would personally go the blank option route (or something like `-- Select --` etc. That's how most dropdowns are styled, whether it's a required field or not.

Comment: Using Ctrl-click to deselect options in a multi-select (and indeed to select multiple non-contiguous options) has been standard behaviour for decades, both for html `<select>` elements and for the equivalent control used by desktop apps (at least for Windows). That _doesn't_ necessarily mean a "normal" user knows that, but still... @ChristianVarga - this isn't a drop-down...

Comment: @nnnnnn oh, I was looking at the jsFiddle in the comments, which doesn't have multiple. Now I see it wasn't even the op who posted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible answers

- show to users to use CTRL to deselect last selected option
- add a blank option
- handle deselection with jquery